# postgres how to add a key to dicts in a jsonb array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I have an array of dicts in a jsonb column. I have to update and add a key to all the dicts in this array. Can this be done in a single update statement?

Jsonb column:

```
select '[{"a":"val1"}, {"b":"val2"}, {"c":"val3"}]'::jsonb;
```

How do I update it to:

```
[
    {
        "a": "val1",
        "x": "xval1"
    },
    {
        "b": "val2",
        "x": "xval2"
    },
    {
        "c": "val3",
        "x": "xval3"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `jsonb_array_elements_text()` function might be used to unnest the elements of `jsonb` data, and then `regexp_replace()` might be applied to get new `jsonb` objects with common keys(`"x"`) within the subquery.

In the next step, `replace()` function together with `jsonb_agg()` would yield the desired result as in the following query :

```
select id,
       jsonb_agg(
                 (replace(jj.value,'}',',')||replace(jsonb_set(value2::jsonb, '{x}',
                 ('"x'||(jj.value2::jsonb->>'x')::text||'"')::jsonb)::text,'{',''))::jsonb
       ) 
    as result
  from
  (
   select t.id, j.value, regexp_replace(j.value,'[[:alpha:]]+','x') as value2
     from t
    cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(jsdata) j
  ) jj
 group by id;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9aa4ada7564dab0e5e0a1fa263de1660)</kbd>

*Indeed, using `'[[:alpha:]]'` pattern for `regexp_replace` is enough, **the plus sign** is added for the cases of the data would have key values with more than one letter.*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dicts have one and only one key:

```
update your_table set
  jsonb_col = (
    select jsonb_agg(
      v || jsonb_build_object(
        'x',
        'x' || (v->>(select min(x) from jsonb_object_keys(v) as x))))
    from jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_col) as v);
```